# How to send an email through strapi without sendgrid

Tags: email, smtp, strapi

I am pretty new to this and I just wanted some clarification over some things.

Basically I am trying to send an email without using any third party plugins like sendgrid. I was reading this documentation of strapi https://strapi.io/documentation/developer-docs/latest/development/plugins/email.html#configure-the-plugin and the first line highlights that strapi provides support for sendmail out of the box. And from my information sendmail can allow sending email without dealing with any third party services.

Now this is the part where I am confused, I have sent emails before through python's SMTP library out there you have to provide credentials for the server you are trying to connect. And this documentation baffles me about how does strapi achieves this.

I tried sending a test email to one of my outlook accounts. However it returns that the test email has failed.

Note: Strapi is on my localhost.

[image]

Now my main question is

Is it possible to send out an email without resorting to these third party services? If so, what are the steps to achieve that. Could it be that its not working because of localhost? And what other options do I have. Basically I do not want to deal with the upper daily limit sendgrid has.

Thanks In Advance

Answer (score 2):

Actually, you can. You will have to set up the provider, there are tons of providers.

Start by looking into the providers page:
check [email providers list](https://www.npmjs.com/search?q=strapi-provider-email-)
If you want to use SMTP like in my case, install the [strapi-provider-email-smtp](https://www.npmjs.com/package/strapi-provider-email-smtp)
`npm i strapi-provider-email-smtp`

Then create a plugins file at: `config/plugins.js` if you dont have it.

Add the corresponding configuration there. i.e.

```
module.exports = ({ env }) => ({
  email: {
    provider: 'smtp',
    providerOptions: {
      host: 'smtp.mailtrap.io',
      port: 2525,
      //secure: true,
      username: '**********',
      password: '9ecbdccff34a9c',
      //rejectUnauthorized: false,
      //requireTLS: false,
      connectionTimeout: 3,
    },
    settings: {
      from: 'info@mail.com',
      replyTo: 'info@mail.com',
    },
  },
  // ...
});
```

There you go, enjoy sending emails trow SMTP or other providers.